# Accessing Sitecore Properties for an Image field in user control's Code-behind

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I want to **access** (and then **modify)** the **properties for the image field**(s) in **Sitecore** (esp. interested in 'Dimensions' and 'Keep Ratio' check box) via a **code-behind file** (blah.ascx.cs). 
[This to ensure that all the images have a consistent size, when displayed in the sublayouts (irrespective of the original size)]

I know these properties can be added manually, but for the case where content authors "forget" to add the dimensions for image(s), I don't want my sublayouts to screw up. Hence, I need a check for that.

**Is there a way to access and then modify these properties via code?**

Here is an image that shows exactly what I want to access and modify via code:

[image]

Comment: Are you using a `FieldRenderer` or a regular `<asp:Image ... />`?

Comment: I am using a regular <asp:Image ... />

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using an `<asp:Image ... />` and binding the `ImageUrl` via C#, you can access the `ImageField` in C# and get the properties, like so:

```
Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField field = item.Fields["My Image Field"];
// you can now access:
//   field.Width
//   field.Height etc...
```

If you're using a `<sc:Image ... />` renderer or a regular `<sc:FieldRenderer ... />` I would recommend you use `<sc:FieldRenderer ... />` as the image parameters only work on that, [as documented here](http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2011/02/28/sitecore-image-parameters/).

Here's a sample snippet:

```
<sc:FieldRenderer FieldName="My Image Field" Parameters="w=100&h=200&as=1" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Perfect! I can get or set the properties now. Thanks!

Another thing though, can I get or set the checkbox **"Keep aspect ratio"**?

Comment: The `Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField` class doesn't have a property for the ratio. The `FieldRenderer` control does take the `as=1` parameter as shown in my example to keep the aspect ratio. To maintain the ratio with the `ImageField` you could do simple division math to the width and height to maintain the ratio.

Comment: Oh yeah! Where did all my brain cells go when I asked you that (stupid) question? Thanks anyways! I'll do the math now! :)

Answer (score 1):

> This to ensure that all the images have a consistent size, when displayed in the sublayouts (irrespective of the original size

I'd suggest to use FieldRenderer class, or **<sc:image>** for rendering such fields in sublayouts, and then specify "**mh**" (max height) and "**mw**" (max width) parameters, so they will always fit into layout.

You can read more about  parameters here - http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/XSL/5%203%20Enhancements/Image%20Enhancements.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Not a 100% sure (can't check here), but if you retrieve the field as an ImageField you should be able to access those values.

```
var cur = Sitecore.Context.Item;
Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField imgfield = cur.Fields["imagefieldname"] as Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField;
//imgfield.<properties>
```